# How to dig through a multidimentional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [PACKAGE] => Array (
      [0] => Array (
        [ATTRIBUTES] => Array (
          [ID] => 0
        )
        [ZIPORIGINATION] => Array (
          [0] => Array (
            [VALUE] => 32751
          )
        )
        [ZIPDESTINATION] => Array (
          [0] => Array (
            [VALUE] => 55967
          )
        )
        [POUNDS] => Array (
          [0] => Array (
            [VALUE] => 0
          )
        )
        [OUNCES] => Array (
          [0] => Array (
            [VALUE] => 9
          )
        )
        [CONTAINER] => Array (
          [0] => Array (
            [VALUE] => Flat Rate Box
          )
        )
        [SIZE] => Array (
          [0] => Array (
            [VALUE] => REGULAR
          )
        )
        [ZONE] => Array (
          [0] => Array (
            [VALUE] => 6
          )
        )
        [POSTAGE] => Array (
          [0] => Array (
            [MAILSERVICE] => Array (
              [0] => Array (
                [VALUE] => Priority Mail<sup>&reg;</sup> Medium Flat Rate Box
              )
            )
            [RATE] => Array (
              [0] => Array (
                [VALUE] => 11.35
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

Array (
  [0] => price Object (
    [mailservice] => Priority Mail<sup>&reg;</sup> Medium Flat Rate Box
    [rate] => 11.35
  )
)
```

...yeah. I need to search through these and pull out the RATE value, which here is 11.35.

For/each loops have failed me so far, any other ideas?

Comment: This is what I get as out put from print_r() I have no idea how to format it. :/

Comment: Use the output in the page source.

Comment: One second, I'll do the formatting for you because that's heinous.

Comment: Digging through your output, it seems you are showing print_r for 2 variables; which value do you want? the value in the first array or in the second?

Comment: Either one really, I'd just like the rate value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function to do this for you:

```
findKey($myarray,$searchKey) {
    foreach($myarray as $key=>$value) {
       if($key==$searchKey) return $value;
       if(is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
           $returned = findKey($value,$searchKey);
           if($returned) return $returned;
       }
    }
    return false;
}

// call it like this:
findKey($yourArray,"rate")
```

Comment: very close to what I was about to answer. one suggestion is to return null instead of false since the desired value may be a boolean.

Comment: Not in the OP's example. But if generalising, the desired value may be a null too!

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class price could not be converted to string in /address/shipping.php on line 24.
It's giving me this error when I try to echo it.